# Automatic discovery of RDS endpoints from EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, service, rds, autodiscovery

I'm very new to AWS and cloud services in general, I'm trying to set up a simple webserver + database stack, as a staging environment before going into production and scaling out. My question regards the discovery of the RDS endpoints from the EC2 instances, is there a way to make it so the instances have an environment variable containing the address to the RDS endpoint? something like Heroku, or is there a better way to do this? Do tools like Consul or CloudFormation help in this regard? I know that RDS endpoint don't change but the configuration would still be manual for example for every instance in autoscaling group right?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation could help, because it has [Outputs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) that inform you of the values on the resources created, there's also [Hashicorp's Terraform](http://terraform.io) which also have an "output" that you could use in your provisioning scripts.

There's also the [aws-cli](https://aws.amazon.com/es/cli/) some config and some sed/awk could help your machines to discover AWS resources from a bash script. If you prefer more sophisticated languages than bash there's also several libraries like python-boto or ruby's fog which can achieve the same result.

Pick your poison.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into `terraform` and it seems that it does provide a way to render templates from variables, which I can use to generate `user_data` scripts for instances. It seems clean enough.